# what is redirect_uri not supported error in facebook oauth

Tags: facebook, oauth

Can we do out of band authentication (oob) with facebook where we specify redirect_uri to be `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` ?

Google clearly mentions it as one of the options:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#formingtheurl

I am trying to do it with facebook and basically using R studio (for running a script on remote server).

I always get an error:

```
The redirect_uri URL is not supported
```

when I point to the url:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=1256802200999873&scope=ads_management&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_type=code

to get an authentication code.

How do I fix this?

Note: I am using package `httr` and here'w what my 2 authentication code looks like:

```
app <- oauth_app('facebook', 'ID', 'SECRET')
Sys.setenv("HTTR_SERVER_PORT" = "1410/")
tkn <- oauth2.0_token(
oauth_endpoints('facebook'),
app,
scope = 'ads_management',
type  = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
use_oob = TRUE,
cache = FALSE)
```

Comment: Read Facebook documentation instead of the oauth2 documentation. Facebook don't allow urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob

Comment: @WizKid: Thank you. :( Is there a fix for this problem then? In browser authentication just does not complete because I am accessing R script on remote server through  R studio. Could you please direct this question to the right place?

Comment: It needs to happen in some kind of browser/webview component.